# Pandas - Mapping integers in one column to strings in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas DataFrame `df` looks like -

```
fileName     objectsIdentified
file_01.jpg  1, 2, 3
file_02.jpg  2, 3
file_03.jpg  1, 2, 4, 2
```

I want to map as per following dict in a new column `objectName`:
`d = {1:'obj1', 2:'obj2', 3:'obj3', 4:'obj4'}`

What did I do? I wrote a function like

```py
def conv(ls):
    global d
    return [d[x] for x in ls]
```

Then I do
`df['objectName'] = df['objectsIdentified'].apply(lambda x: conv(x))`

Received output:

```
fileName     objectsIdentified  objectName  
file_01.jpg  1, 2, 3            obj1, obj2, obj3  
file_02.jpg  2, 3               obj2, obj3  
file_03.jpg  1, 2, 4, 2         obj1, obj2, obj4, obj2
```

**Question** - Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to define our own function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension solution - for each value of `objectsIdentified` first split, then map converted value to integers in generator and last `join`:

```
df['objectName']=[', '.join(d[int(y)] for y in x.split(', ')) for x in df['objectsIdentified']]
print (df)
      fileName objectsIdentified              objectName
0  file_01.jpg           1, 2, 3        obj1, obj2, obj3
1  file_02.jpg              2, 3              obj2, obj3
2  file_03.jpg        1, 2, 4, 2  obj1, obj2, obj4, obj2
```

Pandas solution - create `Series` by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), convert to integers, [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and last use join per groups:

```
df['objectName'] = (df['objectsIdentified'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
                                           .stack()
                                           .astype(int)
                                           .map(d)
                                           .groupby(level=0)
                                           .apply(', '.join))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think you are better to use list comprehension with `str.split` and `str.join`

```
df['objectName'] = [', '.join(map(lambda y: d[int(y)], x.split(','))) 
                                                  for x in df.objectsIdentified]

Out[536]:
      fileName objectsIdentified        objectName
0  file_01.jpg           1, 2, 3  obj1, obj2, obj3
1  file_02.jpg              2, 3        obj2, obj3
2  file_03.jpg           1, 2, 4  obj1, obj2, obj4
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy L. list comprehension would have been better than function! I was hoping there would be a pandas method to achieve the same.

Comment: @AccLok: Glad I could help :). To use native pandas, you need to chain several methods to achieve the result. There is no direct method from Pandas. I recommended list comprehension in this case because I think it will be faster than chaining several methods of pandas; espcially involving splitting, replacing and joinning back... If it is possible, you could `timeit` the speed of your real data between native pandas and list comprehension to see the speed difference ;)